# Check if a dataGridView has errorText set on any of it's cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I know if a datagridview has errorText on any of it's cells. I have a Save button which I want to enable only if all cell values are valid meaning that none of the cells have errorText set

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this method on your code:

```
private bool HasErrorText()
    {
        bool hasErrorText = false;
        //replace this.dataGridView1 with the name of your datagridview control
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ErrorText.Length > 0)
                {
                    hasErrorText = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (hasErrorText)
                break;
        }

        return hasErrorText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution in the accepted answer. I cannot comment, so here is my comment in a new answer:

Don't forget the ErrorText of the row and add this below the first "foreach":

```
if (row.ErrorText.Length > 0)
{
    hasErrorText = true;
    break;
}
```